# Best practice on storing Node.js Buffer in MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

How to store `Buffer` in MySQL with Node.js?
One way I know is to convert `Buffer` to *hex string* and save it as `CHAR` type in MySQL. But is it the best practice to transform *before* and *after* saving in MySQL?

Is there a way that can directly save and get the `Buffer` (bytes array) in MySQL with Node.js, for example, using `BLOB` in MySQL?

Or actually it doesn't matter what kind of way I use, they don't differ so much?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not aware of a best practice. But I can share what works for me.

If I'm working with objects, I prefer storing them as base64 (to cut down on character length over base16) in a `longtext` column and gzipping them .

It's more helpful to store them as strings, I think, because if you store them as buffers, then I don't think there is a way to copy them out of the database (it's really helpful troubleshooting sometimes), and translate them back to your object - at least, I haven't found a way to do that.

For example (assuming Nodejs 6+ for `Buffer.from()` syntax, otherwise use `new Buffer()`):

```
const obj = {};
const zip = zlib.gzipSync(JSON.stringify(obj)).toString('base64');
```

And, undoing:

```
const originalObj = JSON.parse(zlib.unzipSync(Buffer.from(zip, 'base64')));
```

Since `longtext` equals ~4GiB, you shouldn't ever hit the limit, unless you have massive objects. But then I suppose you have an efficiency problem elsewhere.

**Note:** There is obviously a lot packed into one line there (i.e. zip, parse, buffer, etc.).

*A lot can fail in that one line.*

So make sure you handle it appropriately.